# Can I use a backreference as an associative array key?

Tags: regex, bash

I'm parsing some logs and want to add content from another source to the resulting txt, based on the username in the log.
What I came up with was to read the additional content to an associative array where the key is the username and the value is the information. I then use sed to replace the line with the line plus the new content, like so:

```
sed -n -e "s/\(user=\)\([a-zA-Z0-9]*\)\s(.*\)/\1\2 \3 more_info=${user_info[\2]}/p" "./log.txt" > "./log_plus.txt"
```

But when I do this the `more_info=` is empty. Am I doing something wrong or is it impossible to do like this?

Comment: No; the array reference is expanded by the shell before `sed` even runs.

Comment: you can easily replicate your string processing in awk and then pass in an array as an argument and extract what you need there (which may not be so easy ;-) ). Still only one process. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround with `bash` regex (w/o `sed`), please try something like:

```
declare -A user_info["username123"]="age:23"    # just an example of user_info
pattern="(user=)([a-zA-Z0-9]*) (.*)"
while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ $line =~ $pattern ]]; then
        printf "%s%s %s more_info=%s\n" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}" "${BASH_REMATCH[3]}" "${user_info["${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"]}"
    fi
done < "./log.txt" > "./log_plus.txt"
```

Example of log.txt:

```
user=username123 blah blah
other lines
```

And the output:

```
user=username123 blah blah more_info=age:23
```

Just for info you can simplify the `printf` line as:

```
printf "%s%s %s more_info=%s\n" "${BASH_REMATCH[@]:1:3}" "${user_info["${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"]}"
```

Hope this helps.